# Filtering one column on an array of values without using UNION

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to create an arbitrary UNION ALL SQL query using SQL code.

Currently, I have these table descriptions.

[image]

[image]

enter image description here

[image]

[image]

For a given app_id value, I am trying to get all its description ids. Then for each of these description ids, I am trying to get the category ids and then the category names to list them out.

I could easily generate SQL code using PHP, but that seems like cheating.

Comment: It sounds to me like you want to `join` these tables together rather than using a `UNION`.  And I don't see anything wrong with using PHP to test things...you are going to end up there anyway.

Comment: I mean i would generate sql code with php. Basically get all the description ids and make a bunch of union statements.

Comment: I don't know how I would do it with a join. I don't understand how it would work. Unfortunately there aren't for loops in SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join those four table using their foreign key relationship and then get the required result set you don't need a loop for this

```
SELECT a.id as app_id,c.cat_name as category_name 
  FROM apps a inner join app_permission ap 
   on ap.app_id=a.id inner join description d 
   on d.desc_id=ap.desc_id inner join categories c
   on c.cat_id=d.cat_id where a.id=$appid;
```

Comment: you dont need union to get it execute this on db you will get the result

Comment: Sir, thank you for your answer. But what is a. what is b. what is c.

Comment: My table names are apps, app_permissions, categories, and descriptions. If you can please explain your code so I can change it to my purpose.

Comment: i have added same name above just add some mappings to short the query     app -> a ; app_permission -> ap and like that execute above query without any change you will get the result

Comment: THANK YOU SIR!! This helps very much. I just had to change the app_permission and description to plural.  Can you quickly add an explanation of the logic behind the code you made?

Comment: its simply joining 4 tables if you have a foreign key relationship between two tables then you can join those two tables using its mapping column

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html please refer this and if its ok mark this answer as accepted it will help others

Comment: I realise that. I'm asking you to explain how the code works. As in what is it doing. I'm interested so I can replicate it later

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115990/discussion-between-mahesh-madushanka-and-ytpillai).